# htaccess - rewrite urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite the URL:

```
http://example.com/file_name
```

to:

```
http://example.com/depictions/file_name.html
```

For example: `http://example.com/application`
to `http://example.com/depictions/application.html`

Answer (score 1):

It makes it a bit easier in terms of optimisation if we assume the `file_name` cannot contain *dots* (this immediately excludes any requests for real files that ordinarily include a file extension - which is delimited by *dot*). Then you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/depictions/$0.html -f
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+$ depictions/$0.html [L]
```

This actually limits the `file_name` to the characters `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen) as denoted by the regex character class `[\w-]`. Consequently, this only checks requests to "files" in the document root (ie. no slashes permitted).

This also tests that the corresponding target `.html` file exists before issuing the internal rewrite.

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Answer (score 0):

For every `file_name`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+) depictions/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: This would result in a rewrite-loop (500 error) since the regex `^(.+)` also matches the _substitution_ string. eg. `/file_name` to `/depictions/file_name.html` to `/depictions/depictions/file_name.html.html` etc. etc.